# Suma de elementos en un array multidimensional en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo este arreglo y necesito sumar todos los valores de maracadores[i][1] **por un lado** y  todos los de la [i][2] **por otro**. Y lo que propongo solo me suma el elemento donde se encuentre el for 2 veces , entonces al final x solo me suma 16.75 + 16.75

```js
var marcadores = [
      ['x',19.04, -98.20],
      ['x', 25.54, -103.40],
      ['x', 20.65, -103.349],
      ['x',16.75,-93.129]

    ];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < marcadores.length; i++) {
      x = marcadores[i][1]+ marcadores[i][1];
      $('#placeholder').html(x);
      // o algo así?
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La forma de sumar todos los valores del array seria la siguiente, acumulando todos los valores en un sumador

Ejemplo de código que funciona.

```
 var marcadores = [
      ['x',19.04, -98.20],
      ['x', 25.54, -103.40],
      ['x', 20.65, -103.349],
      ['x',16.75,-93.129]

    ];
    var sumador=0;
    for (var i = 0; i < marcadores.length; i++) {
      sumador = sumador+marcadores[i][1]+ marcadores[i][2];

    }
```

Aparte de eso en tu código estas sumando dos veces lo mismo x = marcadores[i][1]+ marcadores[i][1];

La forma de sumar ambas columnas por separado involucra dos sumadores

```
 var marcadores = [
      ['x',19.04, -98.20],
      ['x', 25.54, -103.40],
      ['x', 20.65, -103.349],
      ['x',16.75,-93.129]

    ];
    var sumadorA=0;
    var sumadorB=0;
    for (var i = 0; i < marcadores.length; i++) {
      sumadorA = sumadorA+marcadores[i][1]
      sumadorB= sumadorB+marcadores[i][2];    
    }


 </script>
```

Saludos.

Comment: disculpa me expresé mal ....

Comment: Espero que sea de tu utilidad. Te pido que te acuerdes de aceptar mi respuesta si te sirvio. Saludos y gracias.

Comment: -si superman verás no es lo que quiero TÚ estas sumando las de i1 e i2 y yo quiero las suma de ambas por separado

Comment: Ok, ok. ya lo vi

Comment: Hola edite la respuesta e incluí la otra opción por el final. Fijate si es lo que necesitas. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Estas sumando dos veces el mismo valor y ademas al poner `x =` solo estás asignando el último valor. Deberías sumárselo a todos los valores que recorres poniendo `x +=`.

Y para sumarlo por separado necesitas dos variables:

```
var marcadores = [
    ['x',19.04, -98.20],
    ['x', 25.54, -103.40],
    ['x', 20.65, -103.349],
    ['x',16.75,-93.129]

];


var valor1 = 0;
var valor2 = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < marcadores.length; i++) {
   valor1  += marcadores[i][1];
   valor2 += marcadores[i][2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para sumar las columnas hay que obtener cuántas filas hay,  así 'marcador[0].length'

```
var valor1 = 0;
var valor2 = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < marcadores[0].length; i++) {
   valor1  += marcadores[i][1];
   valor2 += marcadores[i][2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quizás con reduce lo puedas hacer muy fácil.

```
array.reduce(function(total, currentValue, currentIndex, arr), initialValue)
```

> *El método reduce() aplica una función a un acumulador y a cada valor de un array (de izquierda a derecha) para reducirlo a un único valor.*

Código:

```js
var marcadores = [
  ['x', 19.04, -98.20],
  ['x', 25.54, -103.40],
  ['x', 20.65, -103.349],
  ['x', 16.75, -93.129]
];

var sumaA = marcadores.reduce(function(sum, col) {
  return sum + col[1];
}, 0);
var sumaB = marcadores.reduce(function(sum, col) {
  return sum + col[2];
}, 0);

document.getElementById("sumaA").innerHTML = sumaA;
document.getElementById("sumaB").innerHTML = sumaB;
```

```html
<label id="sumaA"></label>
<label id="sumaB"></label>
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp
- https://jsfiddle.net/8Lceq379/2/

Comment: Esta es la mejor respuesta, pero ¿por qué el texto en inglés? ¿Y por qué el ejemplo en jsfiddle en vez de ponerlo en un snippet dentro de la misma respuesta?... Por otro lado, podrías calcular ambos valores dentro de la misma llamada a `reduce()`.

Comment: Si ,pero parecía que quería separar los  valores para mostrarlos en algún sitio. Intentaré poner en español , disculpar.

Comment: A eso me refiero, se puede calcular por separado (pero eso era más bien un comentario extra que no modifica mucho el tema)... Por ejemplo, `marcadores.reduce((acum,elem) => [acum[0] + elem[1],acum[1] + elem[2]], [0,0])` ;-)